# How to align a raycast with mousepostition in Unity with an isometric camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Im having trouble figuring out how to make up for the offset from the mouseposition, when the mouse is not centered. The camera in Unity is at angles (30, 45, 0) and is orthographic. See images for an example.

I thought about rendering a crosshair at the raycast position, but that would still make the aim be tricky.

[image: Example Image]

**Raycast for linerenderer code:**

```
void Shoot ()
 {
     timer = 0f;

     gunAudio.Play ();

     gunLight.enabled = true;

     gunParticles.Stop ();
     gunParticles.Play ();

     gunLine.enabled = true;
     gunLine.SetPosition (0, transform.position);

     shootRay.origin = transform.position;
     shootRay.direction = transform.forward;

     if(Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, shootableMask))
     {
         EnemyHealth enemyHealth = shootHit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

         if(enemyHealth != null)
         {
             enemyHealth.TakeDamage (damagePerShot, shootHit.point);
         }
         gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootHit.point);
     }
     else
     {
         gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootRay.origin + shootRay.direction * range);
     }
 }
```

**Raycast for turning the player:**

```
void Turning()
 {
     Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

     RaycastHit floorHit;

     if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
     {
         Vector3 playerToMouse = new Vector3(floorHit.point.x, transform.position.y, floorHit.point.z);
         transform.LookAt(playerToMouse);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Player seems to be rotated corectly to me.

---

For the LineRenderer / shoot raycast you are not checking for hitting a floor only enemies. So in the `else` block you do

```
gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootRay.origin + shootRay.direction * range);
```

which continues the ray to "eternity" (or `range`) in the given direction.
You should also here add the floor to the `floorMask` so your ray also hits the floor.

Or you could combine the layer values using something like

```
 if(Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, shootableMask | floorMask))
```